# Tree Data structure C# to JS

Tags: c#, javascript, tree, jstree

I have a c# tree structure that will be passed to my JS code in order to populate a hierarchy of drop down lists.

Is there an efficient way to pass C# tree using JSON and then traverse the tree on the JS side(without me having implement a tree structure on both sides, since I already have a C# tree)?

Comment: We use jsTree at work and have a corresponding class for the nodes in C#, populate them in C# and voila. See http://www.jstree.com/

Comment: I need a data structure, not an actual UI tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your C# tree structure serializable?  There are several JSON serializers for .NET:

http://json.codeplex.com/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text

etc...

Answer (score 0):

How about CIL to JavaScript converter?

- https://github.com/chrisdunelm/DotNetWebToolkit

> Cil2Js: A CIL (.NET bytecode) to JavaScript converter